# After pod update getting error 'GoogleUtilities/Environment/Public/GoogleUtilities/GULURLSessionDataResponse.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, google-mlkit

After the Pod update getting many compilation error for `import` any of `GoogleUtilities` in FireBase pods
`'GoogleUtilities/Environment/Public/GoogleUtilities/GULURLSessionDataResponse.h' file not found`

my `Podfile` looks like this

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'project_name' do
  use_frameworks!
  
  # Pods for project_name
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning'
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection'
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/ObjectDetection'
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/ObjectDetectionCustom'
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/PoseDetection'
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/PoseDetectionAccurate'
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/SegmentationSelfie'
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  ...
  ...
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solutions from **Firebase Docs**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup?authuser=8&hl=en#available-pods

> For apps that use **CocoaPods**, the **Firebase** pod is deprecated in **v9.0 and higher**. Instead, you need to reference product pods directly in your Podfile (for example, `FirebaseCore` instead of `Firebase/Core` and `FirebaseFirestore` instead of `Firebase/Firestore`).

and I followed the below steps to resolve it

#### Step 1.

Removed all derived data

#### Step 2.

Updated the `Podfile` as below 
by Uncommented global platform definition and specify the min iOS to 12.0

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'project_name' do
  use_frameworks!
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

and by removing `/` from all Firebase pods

```
  ...
  ...
  ...
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'FirebaseCore'
  pod 'FirebaseDatabase'
  pod 'FirebaseAuth'
  pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'
  pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore'
  pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics'
  pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

#### Step 3.

```
pod deintegrate
```

#### Step 4.

Now go to the finder and locate your project folder,
remove the `Podfile.lock` file and `project.xcworkspace`

#### Step 5.

```
pod install
```

#### Step 6.

After successful installation of all `pods`, open your newly created `project.xcworkspace`

#### Step 7.

Press `⌘⇧K` to clean your project 
And then build freshly by pressing `⌘B`

That's it all errors are gone and the project builds freshly with updated pods. 
Enjoy coding!!